# Single dimensional array from a while loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to retrieve the value of an array which is inside a while loop and use it outside .

I was able to do it with this code

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {

        $xyz[] = $row2;
    } 
echo $xyz;
```

But I am getting a 2 dimensional array when I print $xyz . can someone tell me how to retrieve the array from the while loop so that it is still a single dimension array

I appreciate any kind of help

Comment: $arrayname['column']; in you case $row2['columnName];

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() returns an ARRAY which your are trying to store in an array . Hence leading to 2D array : `    $str=array("dsd","sds");$row[]=$str; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the name of the column in the row you're interested in then you're just going to add the entire row.

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {

        $xyz[] = $row2['whatever_your_column_name_is'];
    } 
print_r $xyz;
```

By the way, the mysql_* functions are deprecated, and it's an not a good idea to use them in new code.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Also, echo will just print the word 'Array'.  If you want to see what's actually in the array then you need print_r or var_dump instead.

Comment: I think you mean `$xyz[] = $row2['whatever_your_column_name_is'];`

Comment: Then I'd appreciate if if you accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$xyz     = array();
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
    {

        $xyz[] = $row2['db field name'];
    } 
echo $xyz;
```